# How do I adjust the size of the background panel for the date-time button drop-down action?

Tags: panel, gnome-shell

I'm using **Ubuntu 17.10** and having a problem with the panel and widgets displayed when I click on the date-time button.  As expected the panel drops down when the button is clicked.  What's not expected is the miscalculation for the size of the background panel.  The panel has at least 2 widgets:  a Notifications widget on the left and the Calendar widget on the right.  The problem is that **the calendar protrudes to the right of the parent panel by about 50%**.  So, I cannot see W-T-F-S entries because they're on a translucent background and my desktop backgrounds are complex photos.  *Is there a quick-and-easy fix to simply adjust the (presumed) common parent background of both widgets?*

[image: Screenshot showing problem]

Comment: Screenshot? Does moving the date/time around the panel change anything?

Comment: @Xen2050: Thanks for the suggestion; I've appended a screenshot to my question.  I've tried the "alt-right-click on the date-time button" -- but I'm not presented with any options for relocating it.  I'm fairly certain, however, that location on upper panel is not a factor... ok, I'm not so certain... it's just a belief of mine. ;)

Comment: do you use any themes maybe? the calendar part looks far bigger that it should be with adwaita or even minwaita theme.

Comment: I was thinking if it were against a screen edge it could've been getting cut off by the screen, but it's right there in the middle so that's not it... Can't expand the calendar/notifications window by dragging it's borders? & If a theme doesn't fix it maybe it's just a bug. If the "Clear All" button at the bottom fixes it that would be a workaround, maybe related to inducing the bug

Comment: It seems the shell theme you're  using is badly written. Open (GNOME) Tweaks and switch a different shell theme.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after exploring with `Tweaks` I found a selection for "Top Bar" which I went to check for moving the clock around... The only related item was `Clock:Date {on|off}` where I selected `off` only to discover that it had not disappeared.  I clicked on it and, voilá!, fixed.  Before this, I changed the theme (there were 3 options and they were out of sync) to be consistent.

I appreciate all who gave me tips and leads by their suggestions and/or questions.  Thank you.